# Problem with animate jquery div with different pace

Tags: javascript, jquery

While I was animating two boxes with jQuery at same pace with setting marginTop, the second box will move faster than the first box.

```
<div id="box1" style="width:500px;height:80px;background-color:blue;">box 1</div>
<div id="box2" style="width:500px;height:80px;background-color:green;margin-left:510px;">box 2</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#box1").animate({marginTop:"-=80px"}, {duration: 1500});            
    jQuery("#box2").animate({marginTop:"-=80px"}, {duration: 1500});
</script>
```

However, when I apply the same setting Top, both box move at same pace.

```
<div id="box1" style="width:500px;height:80px;background-color:blue;position:relative;">box 1</div>
<div id="box2" style="width:500px;height:80px;background-color:green;margin-left:510px;position:relative;">box 2</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#box1").animate({top:"-=80px"}, {duration: 1500});          
    jQuery("#box2").animate({top:"-=80px"}, {duration: 1500});
</script>
```

Any idea why this happening this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the effect more clearly in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AR5FG/2/)

The reason why it is happening is because your second `div` is below the first `div`.  And the `margin` property is relative to the elements surrounding it.  The top div will move slower because the element that is above (in this case the `body`) is not moving.  But your div on the bottom has to move faster in order to maintain that `margin` property relative to the element above it.  In other words, it wants to MAINTAIN that property once the animation is finished.

In my fiddle, each `div` starts with `margin-top: 100px`.  Now when they are animated, they want to `marginTop: "-=80px"`, which means that they need to end up at `margin-top: 20px`.  In the top elements case, it only needs to move 80px upward, because `body` isn't moving.  But the bottom `div` needs to move 80px PLUS the amount that the top `div` moved, which is another 80px, for a total of 160px.  The `div` needs to move 2x the amount of pixels in the same amount of time, so it will move faster.

We can further illustrate that the `margin` property is a relative property from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AR5FG/4/).  Even though I'm only animating the top `div`, the bottom `div` is moving too because it needs to keep that `margin` value consistent.

The reason why your second piece of code allows the `div`s to move at the same speed is because the `top` property is not a relative property of any element besides it's container (the right container that is, probable that it's not it's direct container), so they will both move at the same speed.

Not sure if this is clear.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very detail explanation.Now only see the reason why it happen this way. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the green box with Firebug or Chrome, you'll see that it's left margin has pushed itself underneath the blue box. It's still technically in line with the blue box, so jQuery calculates the end position (in line with the blue box). They end up next to each other at the same time just like your second example, but it just looks different. In the second example they look inline, so appear to move inline. This is what I have observed, anyway.